# Facebook browser does not fire custom schemes

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I have a website that when loaded will use javascript to open up a custom url example://test that will trigger the app that has registered the example:// url scheme. This works fine in safari and chrome, but when clicking for example the website's url in a Facebook post or sending the link over via Facebook messenger, these apps will load their own browser and this browser won't do the redirection unless if I press (once in the Facebook browser) share/show in safari. Is this a bug? is there a work around for this?

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />`
seems to do the job.

Make sure to force-refresh the url you are using, using this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to branch.io users.. I asked facebook through their developer support, and they said they would fix it in v.45 - but i just installed v.45 and it still doesn't work.